# Implemenation of CIS Benchmark rule in Linux Hardening, we have issue in one of the rule which is "Ensure use of privileged commands is collected "

Tags: linux, ansible

We are working on Linux OS hardening as per CIS Benchmark rules. We are using this command prompt to verify our rule which is "Ensure SSH root login is disabled (Automated)".

Input Command:

```
find <partition> -xdev \( -perm -4000 -o -perm -2000 \) -type f | 
    awk '{print "-a always,exit -F path=" $1 " -F perm=x -F auid>='"$(awk '/^\s*UID_MIN/{print $2}' /etc/login.defs)"' -F auid!=4294967295 -k privileged" }'
```

Output Command:

> Verify all resulting lines are a `.rules` file in `/etc/audit/rules.d/` and the output of `auditctl -l`.

We have configured linux defender firewall with the help of ansible and trying to fetch values in command prompt. But in command prompt we are unable to fetch privilege process with above input command and using partition manually and also in `/etc/audit/rules.d` folder when we make change in content of any of .rules files , even after system reboot the changes is not reflected in `auditctl -l` command.

Can you please help us ansible script writing part where we get our desired output ?

Comment: The command you've posted has nothing at all to do with disabling SSH root login: it seems to be about audit rules. Did you make a copy/paste error in your second bullet point?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question, I am not able to understand your question. Also, just want to inform you, we don't have ssh root login issue, actually we are not getting all files of /etc/audit/rules from command auditctl -l. Request you to please provide some solution.

Comment: Your question says "...using this command prompt to verify our rule which is "Ensure SSH root login is disabled (Automated)". This disagrees with your question title and I think is just a copy/paste mistake. Please edit your question to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `<partition>` should be replaced with whatever part of filesystem you are wishing to create audit rules for. The most common case would probably be creating audit rules for the whole system: in that case, you should replace `<partition>` with just `/`.

The wording of the command example is a bit misleading here: in this case, `<partition>` does **not** refer to a **disk partition** like `/dev/sda1`, but just the part of the filesystem tree you wish to create audit rules for.

The command will output the rules to standard output: to use them, you should redirect the output to an appropriate file. If you are *creating* audit rules, you might simply redirect the output to e.g. `/etc/audit/rules.d/cis.rules`, and then run `auditctl -R /etc/audit/rules.d/cis.rules` to make them take effect immediately:

```
find / -xdev \( -perm -4000 -o -perm -2000 \) -type f | 
    awk '{print "-a always,exit -F path=" $1 " -F perm=x -F auid>='"$(awk '/^\s*UID_MIN/{print $2}' /etc/login.defs)"' -F auid!=4294967295 -k privileged" }' \
    > /etc/audit/rules.d/cis.rules
```

If you are *verifying* existing rules, you should redirect the output to a temporary file, then compare it to the existing rules file in `/etc/audit/rules.d/` directory. For ease of comparing, you might want to sort both files first, so any differences can be easily viewed with `diff` or a similar tool.

So a simple verification script might be:

```
#!/bin/sh
ACTUAL_RULES=/etc/audit/rules.d/cis.rules

# Create a temporary directory and set it to auto-delete on script exit   
WORKDIR=$(mktemp -d) && trap "rm -rf $WORKDIR" EXIT

# Create a sorted set of what the rules should be
find / -xdev \( -perm -4000 -o -perm -2000 \) -type f | 
    awk '{print "-a always,exit -F path=" $1 " -F perm=x -F auid>='"$(awk '/^\s*UID_MIN/{print $2}' /etc/login.defs)"' -F auid!=4294967295 -k privileged" }' |
    sort > $WORKDIR/cis.rules.sorted.should-be

# sort the actual rules
sort < $ACTUAL_RULES >$WORKDIR/cis.rules.sorted.actual

# compare expected vs. actual
diff -u $WORKDIR/cis.rules.sorted.should-be $WORKDIR/cis.rules.sorted.actual
```

If the script produces no output (return code is 0), the verification is successful.

If there are differences between expected & actual rules, the script will exit with return code 1, and the `diff -u` output will indicate extra rules (prefixed with a single `+`) and missing rules (prefixed with a single `-`).
If `diff` can colorize its output in your distribution, the extra rules will be output in green and missing rules in red.